# Validate Rails attribute presence but allow empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I want to validate a string attribute is not nil, but allow empty strings.

As in:

```
validates name: not_nil, allow_empty: true
```

Answer (score 8):

you could also do:

```
validates :name, exclusion: { in: [nil] }
```

Answer (score 3):

To allow an empty string, but reject nil in an active record validation callback, use a conditional proc to conditionally require the presence of the attribute if it's not nil.

So the code looks like:

```
validates :name, presence: true, if: proc { name.nil? }
```

But you probably want to allow null. Then don't validate. Still check for presence? in code for nil or empty string.

Comment: You should probably just write a custom validation method, it's extremely confusing to use `validates presence: true` on a field that is meant to contain empty strings. That's the opposite of what that validator is meant to enforce.

Comment: Well, it works. The validation runs only when name is nil, and triggers an error. The validation won't run if it's anything not nil ("" is accepted)

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively

```
validates :name, presence: true, allow_blank: true
```

Comment: `allow_blank` will also allow `nil` values, even with `presence: true`.